# MYSQL INSERT based on values from 3 columns

Tags: mysql, if-statement, formula, sql-insert

I have a mysql database and I would like to do an SELECT/INSERT based on the conditions of three different numeric fields: (HI, OT and WC).

I want to INSERT into a field called AT the value of the following condition:

```
HI if HI > OT
else
WC if WC < OT
else 
OT
```

Something like this, but I cannot seem to get it correct:

```
INSERT INTO variations (AT)
SELECT

HI if HI > OT
else
WC if WC < OT
else
OT,
FROM archive;
```

Comment: Don't insert statements usually have a VALUES clause in them?

Comment: You can't use `IF` in a query statement. You must use [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html). You should consult the documentation on the syntax for each statement when trying to use it, that'll guide you towards a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
mysql> INSERT INTO variations (AT)
     ->SELECT CASE WHEN HI > OT THEN HI
     ->WHEN WC < OT THEN WC ELSE OT END FROM archive;
```

Comment: if it works, can you mark the question as answered !

Answer (score 0):

It's seems a bit strange that you're inserting rows with a single column into table. That's not invalid, but it is a bit odd.

First, write the SELECT statement.   Note that `IF` is not a valid keyword in MySQL. The closest ANSI-standard equivalent is a `CASE` expression. And MySQL also  conveniently offers a non-standard `IF()` function.

```
  SELECT CASE 
           WHEN t.hi > t.ot THEN t.hi 
           WHEN t.wc < t.ot THEN t.wc
           ELSE t.ot
         END AS `at` 
    FROM archive t
```

To test this, you probably want to include some other columns in the SELECT list so you can verify the result and/or include some predicates in a WHERE clause.

```
  SELECT CASE 
           WHEN t.hi > t.ot THEN t.hi 
           WHEN t.wc < t.ot THEN t.wc
           ELSE t.ot
         END AS `at`
       , t.hi
       , t.wc
       , t.ot
    FROM archive t
```

That's just for testing. Once you've got a SELECT that is returning the rows you want to insert, then just before the `SELECT` add

```
  INSERT INTO variations (`at`)
```

and you'll be good to go.

NOTE: It's *not* mandatory to enclose the column name "at" in backticks, since it's not a MySQL reserved word. But I tend to put backticks around all identifiers (e.g. column names) that are MySQL keywords (even if they aren't reserved words.)

MySQL does have alternatives to a `CASE` expression. An equivalent result can be obtained with an expression that nests MySQL `IF()` functions. For example:

```
  SELECT IF(t.hi>t.ot,t.hi,IF(t.wc<t.ot,t.wc,t.ot)) AS `at` 
    FROM archive t
```

NOTE: The expression `IF(x,y,z)` causes MySQL to evaluate `x` as a boolean, and if `x` evaluates to TRUE then return `y` else return `z`.